# How to mock a bean with @Qualifier

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a class which has a Bean with @Qualifier (See AerospikeClient). While writing test cases, I am unable to mock the bean using @MockBean. I always get null pointer exception for aerospikeClient inside verify(aerospikeClient).put

My class

```
package com.a.recharge.service.impl;

import com.aerospike.client.*;
import com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy;
import com.a.recharge.entity.aero.PacksInfo;
import com.a.recharge.service.AerospikeService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class AerospikeServiceImpl implements AerospikeService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("oldAerospikeClient")
    private AerospikeClient aerospikeClient;

    @Value("${config.aerospike.defaultNS:test}")
    private String nameSpace;

    @Value("${config.aerospike.set.txn:''}")
    private String setname;

    @Value("${config.aerospike.ttl:1800}")
    private int ttl;

    @Value("${config.aerospike.defaultNS}")
    public String defaultNS;

    @Value("${config.aerospike.host}")
    private String aerospikeHost;

    @Value("${config.aerospike.port}")
    private String aerospikePort;

    @Value("${config.aerospike.userName}")
    public String aerospikeUserName;

    @Value("${config.aerospike.password}")
    public String aerospikePassword;

    @Value("${config.aerospike.expiration}")
    public long expiration;

    @Value("${config.aerospike.expiration.no}")
    public long noExpiration;


    @Override
    public void insertRecord(String keyString, PacksInfo packsInfo) {
        // log.info("Saving Records in Aerospike, " + keyString+ ", "+ packsInfo);
        WritePolicy writePolicy = new WritePolicy();
        writePolicy.expiration = ttl; // seconds
        writePolicy.sendKey = true;

        // columns
        Bin[] bins = new Bin[3];

        bins[0] = new Bin("type", packsInfo.getClass().getName());
        bins[2] = new Bin("@user_key", keyString);
        bins[1] = new Bin("value", packsInfo);

        try {
            Key key = new Key("test", "PacksInfo", keyString);
            aerospikeClient.put(writePolicy, key, bins);
        } catch (AerospikeException e) {
            log.error("Exception raised. Root Cause {}, Message {}", ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e),
                      ExceptionUtils.getMessage(e));
        }
    }

    

}
```

My test class

```
package com.a.recharge.service;

import com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient;
import com.aerospike.client.Bin;
import com.aerospike.client.Host;
import com.aerospike.client.Key;
import com.aerospike.client.policy.ClientPolicy;
import com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy;
import com.a.recharge.config.AerospikeConfiguration;
import com.a.recharge.service.impl.AerospikeServiceImpl;
import com.a.recharge.util.CollectionUtil;
import com.a.recharge.util.TestUtil;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.*;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
// @SpringBootTest(classes = AerospikeServiceImpl.class)

public class AerospikeServiceImplTest {

    @Mock(name ="oldAerospikeClient")
    private AerospikeClient aerospikeClient;// = TestUtil.getAerospikeClient();

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<WritePolicy> captor1;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Key> captor2;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Bin[]> captor3;

    @InjectMocks
//    @Autowired
    AerospikeServiceImpl aerospikeService;

//    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
//    public void setUp() {
//        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
//    }


    @Test
    public void checkInsert(){
        Mockito.doNothing().when(aerospikeClient).put(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
        Mockito.verify(aerospikeClient).put(captor1.capture(), captor2.capture(), captor3.capture());
        aerospikeService.insertRecord(TestUtil.keyString, TestUtil.getPacksInfo());

        assertEquals(1800, captor1.getValue().expiration);
        assertEquals(true, captor1.getValue().expiration);
    }
}
```

i changed to InjectMocks and used Mockito.doNothing(), But still the same error.
Is it because the put method of aerospikeClient is final?

Another question is that for testing the AerospikeServiceImpl class should I autowire it directly as above or create a bean like this?

```
@TestConfiguration
    static class AerospikeServiceImplTestContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public AerospikeServiceImpl AerospikeServiceImpl() {
            return new AerospikeServiceImpl();
        }
    }
```

I am relatively new to Spring Boot, so any best practices' advice will be highly appreciated.

My final test class. It works. No need of @TestConfiguration.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AerospikeServiceImplTest {

    @Mock //(name ="oldAerospikeClient")
    private AerospikeClient aerospikeClient;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Key> captor2;

    @InjectMocks
//    @Autowired
    private AerospikeServiceImpl aerospikeService;

    @Test
    public void checkInsert(){
        aerospikeService.insertRecord(TestUtil.keyString, TestUtil.getPacksInfo());

        Mockito.verify(aerospikeClient).put(captor1.capture(), captor2.capture(), captor3.capture());
        assertEquals("test", captor2.getValue().namespace);
        assertEquals("PacksInfo", captor2.getValue().setName);
        assertEquals("MOBILE_JIOPREPAID_GJ", captor2.getValue().userKey.toString());

    }
```

Comment: According to the doco (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) MockBean with Qualifier is supported.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Unit Tests or Integration Tests? You are mixing both (MockitoJUnitRunner and SpringBootTest). You have @InjectMocks commented also. Please review a tutorial like this: https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-unit-testing-and-mocking-with-mockito-and-junit and go from there.

Comment: I am trying to write unit tests, as I was getting null pointer error, so I was trying with SpringBootTest. I tried with InjectMocks too. Still the same error. Could you run it on your local and check?

Comment: The `@Qualifier` is irrelevant in your current setup you are only using Mockito. Another thing that is wrong with your test is that your `verify` call should be after the `insertRecord` call not before. Finally you get an error/stacktrace please include that into your question and point to the line that is actually generating the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.a.recharge.service.AerospikeServiceImplTest.checkInsert(AerospikeServiceImplTest.java:76)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)

Comment: The aerospikeClient is null, here
Mockito.verify(aerospikeClient).put(captor1.capture(), captor2.capture(), captor3.capture());
hence  the test cases are failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aerospikeClient.put() is a final method. Mockito 2 now supports mocking final methods but this feature has to be explicitly activated ; it can be done via the mockito extension mechanism by creating the file src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker containing a single line:

mock-maker-inline
Please refer to this link: [https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods)

Comment: I added this file test/resources/mockito-extensions 
with this line : mock-maker-inline. 
It works. Thanks.